# Hi, non-mathematician here, looking for any proof regarding gimbal lock being unavoidable for 3-value rotation representations

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations, kinematics, computer-vision

So while there are many CG-oriented guides explaining gimbal-lock, they always jump into quaternions without first stating the necessity for doing so in that it's a dead end for deriving rotations using three separate angular values with any specific order. Has it already been shown mathematically (and programically) that there's no way to make unavoidable singularities, flipping, and/or gimbal lock for 3d rotation constructed from any arbitrarily selected triplet of numbers?

Comment: quaternions are actually ta natural setting to discuss three dimensional rotations. Read about their origins here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Hamiltonian_quaternions

Comment: IIRC this is, indeed, well known. My recollection is that a proof hinges on the manifold of all rotations (that is, the 3-dimensional "surface" of a 4-dimensional sphres) being non-homeomorphic to the 3-fold Cartesian product of the circle (each circle giving one of the Euler angles). More briefly, $S^3$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$. There's a bit more to do (to force a problematic point to any mapping between the two spaces), but I'm not a topologist. Let's wait for one :-)

Comment: ...The story about Halmiltonian's lack of a pocket notepad is one of my favorites, but thanks anyway...

Comment: Here’s the start of some cool videos on the topic: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ